# Force produced by an electron beam

Tags: electric-fields

Suppose an electron beam hits a positively charged plate, what is the force on the plate?
I was thinking that the force on the plate is equal to the sum of the electric field produced by the plate at a distance d where an electron is found, times the charge of each electron
Assuming that there are n electrons in the beam, we have
[image]
I am right?

[image]

Comment: Don't confuse force with energy or momentum.

Comment: Is it an infinite plate or has finite dimensions?

Comment: @TheSmartTurtle finite dimensions

Comment: The sum needs to turn into a surface integral, from $d=0$ to $d=\infty$ and you need account with perhaps elastic scattering of the beam on the surface, aka, what matters in this whole picture is only the initial electron beam velocity

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate over the surface of the charged plate and the length of the beam.

Suppose the plate is a circular disc with radius $R$ and charge density $\sigma$, total electric force on plate by n electrons at distance $d$ is

$$F(d) = 2\pi n\sigma(1-\frac{d}{\sqrt{d^2+R^2}})$$

(See [this](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Ewatson/phys208/exercises/kevan/efield1.html) for derivation.)

Then integrate over the length of electron beam. Suppose it starts from $d=L$ to $d=0$, the total force is

$$F=\int_0^LF(d)dd=2\pi n\sigma (L- \int_0^L \frac{d}{\sqrt{d^2+R^2}}dd )$$